# Access denied when using PHP Curl script posting a website

Tags: php, curl, post

I am using a script using curl on posting to a website. When i just use my regular browser on the website its working. But when i use my script i get 'acces denied' and reference thing.The website is blocking my request when i use my curl php script. Does anyone knows how to fix this? Thanks!

Here is a part of my script.

```
     $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.convergepay.com/hosted-payments/service/payment/hpe/process');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, ''.$user_agent.'');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, getcwd().'/cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, getcwd().'/cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                                                'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
                                                'Host: www.convergepay.com',
                                                'Origin: https://classicappreciation.com/',
                                                'Referer: https://classicappreciation.com/'
                                                                                ));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{"fields":{"ssl_transaction_type":"ccverify","ssl_salestax":"0","ssl_first_name":"MAR","ssl_last_name":"KO","ssl_company":"SADA","ssl_avs_address":"11 3rd St","ssl_address2":"APT, SUITE, BLDG. (OPTIONAL...","ssl_city":"Newark","ssl_state":"NJ","ssl_avs_zip":"07107","ssl_country":"USA","ssl_email":"deoei6@gmail.com","ssl_phone":"2342424243","ssl_invoice_number":100254,"ssl_amount":15"}}');
    $card = curl_exec($ch);
```

I already tried to add some CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER but it doesn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: Use the browser F12 tools to see everything that is being sent.  You might be missing authentication or session cookies, other headers, one-time-tokens / nonce,  a mac hash .....  . If you see tokens, sessions, cookies realize they are tied to that browser session so you can't just paste the values into cURL.

Comment: The following may be helpful: [Converge Overview](https://developer.elavon.com/na/docs/converge/1.0.0/overview), and [Hosted Payments](https://developer.elavon.com/na/docs/converge/1.0.0/integration-guide/integration_methods/hosted_payments),